# MySQL 8.0 procedure out param is null

Tags: mysql

#### Synopsis

I'm writing a MySQL stored procedure that contains two `IN` parameters and a single `OUT` parameter. The value of the `OUT` parameter appears to be null.

What am I doing wrong here?

#### Reproduction Steps

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cbtgeo.add123;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE cbtgeo.add123 (IN val1 INT, IN val2 INT, OUT val3 INT) 
    BEGIN
        SET val3 = @val1 + @val2;
    END//
    
DELIMITER ;

SET @myvar222 = NULL;
CALL cbtgeo.add123(5,6, @myvar222);
SELECT @myvar222;
```

#### Expected Result

```
+-----------+
| @myvar222 |
+-----------+
|        11 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Actual Result

```
+-----------+
| @myvar222 |
+-----------+
|      NULL |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### What I've Tried

- Initializing `@myvar222` to `0` instead of `NULL`
- Using `SET @val3 ...` instead of `SET val3 ...`

Answer (score 2):

I finally just figured it out.

When you're referencing `IN` parameters in the body of the stored procedure, you don't use the `@` sign.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cbtgeo.add123;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE cbtgeo.add123 (IN val1 INT, IN val2 INT, OUT val3 INT) 
    BEGIN
        SET val3 = val1 + val2;
    END//
    
DELIMITER ;

SET @myvar222 = NULL;
CALL cbtgeo.add123(5,6, @myvar222);
SELECT @myvar222;
```

#### Result

```
+-----------+
| @myvar222 |
+-----------+
|        11 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Correct - in MySQL, `@` is a sigil only for [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). Not for procedure parameters or [local variables defined with DECLARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html). In some other SQL implementations e.g. Microsoft, the `@` sigil is used differently.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context @BillKarwin.